Intersect a 'circular' sector with a 'square' on WGS84
I wold like to get the intersection(if empty or not) and area of a circular sector defined by the origin(lat, lon), bearing and angle width with a 'square' defined by lines of constant lat and lon on the WGS84 ellipsoid.
Is there a python package that can compute this exactly, or are there any articles that deal with this issue?

This is simply polygon intersection on the ellipsoid, lots of questions here deal with that
